# receiving error code every time i try execute

Tags: mysql-workbench

Select c.CategoryName,COUNT(p1.ProductID) as CountOfProduct, MAX(p1.ListPrice) as MaxOfProduct

From Categories as c1 JOIN products as p1

ON c1.CategoryID=p1.CategoryID

Group By c1.CategoryName

Order By CountOfProduct DESC

Comment: c1.ctegoryname, did you mistype the alias for first column in your query

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.